# Migrating from spring-cloud 2020.0.6 to 2021.0.8

Tags: spring-boot, migration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

i've started migration from spring-cloud 2020.0.6 to 2021.0.8 but i can't find any migration guide between this two libs. I've also tried to search specifically for spring-cloud-gateway (from 3.0.8 to 3.1.8) but i can't find any migration guide also in this project.

Comment: There are release notes. Are you experiencing any problems?

Comment: i can't find any reference on migration between versions on release note. Maybe migration is simply related to migration of spring boot version?